# Scrip para Rellenar 2 tablas de base de datos relacionadas en Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Buenas, actualmente me encuentro realizando un sistema para gestionar una biblioteca y busco un metodo para rellenar dos tablas relacionadas, por ejemplo: tengo en mi base de datos la tabla **libros** y la tabla **autores** ambas relacionadas por sus respectivos id. individualmente relleno los datos de la tabla con este tipo de scrips:

```
<div class="form-group">
{!!Form::label('titulo','Titulo:')!!}
{!!Form::text('titulo',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingresa el Titulo del Libro'])!!}
```

si alguien es tan amable de pasarme un ejemplo para introducir por ejemplo (valga la redundancia) el nombre del autor en la tabla libros y que este tambien llene la tabala autores estaria agradecido.

disculpen si no me di a entender soy nuevo usando este framework.

Comment: No me queda claro que es lo que quieres, ¿Llenar con datos de prueba las tablas de la base de datos?

Comment: No queda claro. Lo que vos queres es entender es como se asocian las tablas y se llenan en el controlador?

Comment: Si, quiero entender a nivel de sintasix por eso pido un ejemplo para llenar y comprobar si funcionan

Answer (score -1):

Amigo entendí mal tu pregunta, creí que querías mostrar los datos de las tablas relacionadas(y luego de haber escrito todo  sobre como realizar el listado me di cuenta que lo que necesitabas era ingresar los datos!!!!! :(  , a la final me toco hacer toda la tarea,déjo un tutoríal de **como listar la información en una tabla** y ademas **como realizar la inserción de la información** + un link de youtube es una lista de reproducción de un curso de Laravel, te lo recomiendo al 100% ahi esta todo),al igual que tu soy novato en esto de larvel. (Por favor estar atentos al código espero no haber olvidado alguna coma o algo).

**Listar la informacion**

**1.-Primero crear la ruta.**

```
Route::resource('libros','LibrosController');
```

**2.-Crear el controlador**, en este caso de tipo resource (controlador que te permite acciones básicas tales como: crear, editar, eliminar, listar), para crear el controlador ejecutas en la consola el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan make:controller LibrosController --resource
```

una ves ejecutado el comando anterior tenemos el controlador con las respectivas funciones (Index, create, store, show, edit, update, destroy), para este ejemplo vamos a trabajar con la función **index** , pero antes de comenzar tienes que agregar a la cabecera del controlador el siguiente código **use DB;** lo colocas justo debajo del namespace de tu aplicación. Ahora si agregar el siguiente código

```
public function index()
    {
        $libros =DB::table('libros as l')
        ->join('autores as a', 'l.clave_foranea', '=', 'a.clave_foranea')
        ->select('l.id_libro','l.nombre_libro','a.autor')
        ->get();
    return view('libros.index',["objeto_libros"=>$libros]);
    }
```

Lo que esta sucediendo es que en la variable $libros se almacena la consulta, deberas editar el nombre de las tabla y agregar los respectivos atributos a si como también los campos con los cuales se conecta la tabla libros y autores.

Una ves ejecutada la consulta retornaremos a la vista **libros.index** un objeto de nombre **objeto_libros** mismo que contendrá toda la información de la tabla, claro esta que dentro de tu carpeta **resources/views/** tienes que crear el archivo índex.

**3.-Crear la vista** que mostrara la tabla con la información respectiva. índex.blade.php

adjunto el código de como debería quedar la tabla para mostrar los registros:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nombre Libro</th>
      <th>Autor</th>
    </thead>
    @foreach($objeto_libros as $libros)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$libros->id_libro}}</td>        
      <td>{{$libros->nombre_libro}}</td>        
      <td>{{$libros->autor}}</td>        
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>
```

**Como realizar una inserción en la base de datos**

1.-Crear el modelo **Libro**.

```
<?php
namespace app;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Libro extends Model
{
    protected $table='libro';
    protected $primaryKey='idlibro';
    public $timestamps=false;
//campos que van a recibir un valor para almacenarlo en la base de datos
    protected $fillable=[
    'titulo',
    'categoria',
    'id_autor'
    ];
}
```

2.- Crear el modelo **Autor**

```
<?php
namespace app;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Autor extends Model
{
    protected $table='autor';
    protected $primaryKey='idautor';
    public $timestamps=false;
//campos que van a recibir un valor para almacenarlo en la base de datos
    protected $fillable=[
    'nombre_autor',
    'apellido_autor'
    ];
```

**3.- en el controlador** de tipo resource que ya explique como crearlo ponemos lo siguiente en la función Store.
(Yo supongo que la gran duda radica en como hacer una inserción en dos tablas al mismo tiempo, es decir insertas el libro y haces heredar el id en la tabla autor o viceversa, entonces aquí tu respuesta)

```
     public function store(IngresoRequest $request){
            try {
              DB::beginTransaction();

              $autor= new Autor;
              $autor->nombre_autor=$request->get('nombre');        
              $autor->apellido_autor=$request->get('apellido');        
              $libro->save();

(Hasta este momento se hace la inserción del nombre y apellido, el id del autor se autogenera,revisar el modelo autor ahí se establece que el campo **protected $primaryKey='idlibro';** es el campo primario se supone que en tu base de datos ese atributo debe ser autoincremental)


                $libro = new Libro();

                $libro->titulo=$request->get('titulo_libro');  
                $libro->categoria=$request->get('categoria_libro');
                $libro->id_autor=$autor->idautor;
                $libro->save();

(Suponiendo que la tabla Libro es la que va a heredar la clave foránea del autor, date cuenta de lo siguiente. el código **$libro->id_autor=$autor->idautor;** dice que va a insertar en el atributo **id_autor** que se encuentra en la tabla Libro(Clave foránea) va a cojer el id que se genero con la primera inserción). así de fácil y sencillo con las inserciones en larvel.


              }
              DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
              DB::rollback();
            }
            return redirect::to('libros');
          }
        }
```

**4.- Crear el request** que es el que va a permitir validar los campos

```
<?php
namespace app\Http\Requests;
use app\Http\Requests\Request;
class libroFormRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'titulo'=>'required|max:50',
            'categoria'=>'required|max:45',
            'nombre_autor'=>'required|max:50',
            'apellido_autor'=>'required|max:50'

        ];
    }
}
```

**5.- Crear el formulario php** con los campos que respectivos en este caso (titulo, categoría, nombre_autor, apellido_autor)

Formulario

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'libros','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}    

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="titulo">Titulo</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo del libro....">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoria" placeholder="Categoria del libro...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nombre_autor">Nombre autor</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre_autor" placeholder="Nombre del autor...">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="apellido_autor">Apellido autor</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido_autor" placeholder="Apellido del autor...">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" name="button" class="">Guardar</button>
    <button type="reset" name="button" class="">Cancelar</button>
  </div>

    {!!Form::close()!!}

  </body>
  </html>
```

**Link del curso:**
[Curso de Laravel 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=togIjDT95wo&list=PLIddmSRJEJ0u-5Nv2k6W8Vhe0wUP_7H5W)

Eso es todo amigo espero te sirva, de todos modos en google y youtube existen varios videotutoriales sobre este tema todo es cuestión de buscar.

Comment: Este código contiene muchos errores y malas prácticas en cuanto a Laravel, PSR-2 y organización de las etapas.